# GET Request URI with multiple params in Java

Tags: java, uri

By using java.net.URI class, how can I render an URI like this?

```
http://www.mysite.org/do_something?username=j.doe?firstName=John?lastName=Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

As found by Googling `java.net.URI`, here's a snippet from the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)

> A hierarchical URI is subject to further parsing according to the
>   syntax
>
> `[scheme:][//authority][path][?query][#fragment]`

And here's a constructor from the same docs.

```
URI(String scheme, String authority, String path, String query, String fragment)
```

So I suppose

```
new URI(http","www.mysite.org","/do_something","username=j.doe&firstName=John&lastName=Doe","");
```

would do the trick.